# Use managed identity of the web app to manage b2c using graph api

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-managed-identity

I have a web app hosted in azure with managed identity enabled on it.
I also have a b2c tenant, in which I registered that application and granted it permissions to list all users.

If I'm using the combination of clientId, tenantId and clientSecret - I can call the GraphServiceClient and get users. But if I'm specifying DefaultAzureCredentials - then it looks like it can't validate the access.

I would really like to avoid the manual client secret rotation, so is there a way to make DefaultAzureCredentials to work? It seems like I missed some assignment IAM, bot there is no GraphApi-related roles. It's also not helping that b2c tenant manager is a separate window with its own UI.

Searching the internet I saw a mention of service-to-service authorization, where having Azure AD we register both app and B2C in there... but may be there is a better way? It should be, at least.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per december 2023, this is not supported as managed identities belong to only one tenant:

> #### [Can I use a managed identity to access a resource in a different directory/tenant?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-faq#can-i-use-a-managed-identity-to-access-a-resource-in-a-different-directorytenant)
>
> No. Managed identities don't currently support cross-directory scenarios.

Additonally I looked into [federated identity credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/workload-id/workload-identities-overview) which should theoretically enable this scenario but it is not supported as well:

> #### [Microsoft Entra issuers aren't supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/workload-id/workload-identity-federation-considerations#microsoft-entra-issuers-arent-supported)
>
> *Applies to: applications and user-assigned managed identities*
>
> Creating a federation between two Microsoft Entra identities from the same or different tenants isn't supported. When creating a federated identity credential, configuring the issuer (the URL of the external identity provider) with the following values isn't supported:
>
> - *.login.microsoftonline.com
> - *.login.windows.net
> - *.login.microsoft.com
> - *.sts.windows.net
>
> While it's possible to create a federated identity credential with a Microsoft Entra issuer, attempts to use it for authorization fail with error `AADSTS700222: AAD-issued tokens may not be used for federated identity flows`.